# how to search a certain part in one field on SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm doing some task using Codeigniter and i have a problem in query search. I have the following data in mysql:

```
order_billing
--------------
19001-00001-32222
13501-00021-31122
13344-02351-16072
18701-00001-30922
11123-12301-12122
```

it have 3 parts format for order_billing : `number_1-number_2-number_3`

and i make search form for like this

```
<input type="text" name="order_billing_1">-
<input type="text" name="order_billing_2">-
<input type="text" name="order_billing_3">
```

how do i can make a SQL query when for with condition

- input "order_billing_1" for search "number_1"
- input "order_billing_2" for search "number_2"
- input "order_billing_3" for search "number_3"

i made some code like this

```
$post = $this->input->post();
$search['number_1'] = $post['order_billing_1'];
$search['number_2'] = "-".$post['order_billing_2'];
$search['number_3'] = "-".$post['order_billing_3'];
```

and the query like this

```
$this->db->like('order_billing', '$search['number_1']', 'after');
$this->db->or_like('order_billing', '$search['number_2']', 'both');
$this->db->or_like('order_billing', '$search['number_3']', 'before');
```

but it still not correct. i still confuse how to search like that in manual SQL query.

```
$search['number_1'] = $post['order_billing_1'];
$search['number_2'] = "-".$post['order_billing_2'];
$search['number_3'] = "-".$post['order_billing_3'];
```

the query

```
Select * from TABLE WHERE order_billing like ????
```

do any one know how to solve this.?

Comment: `'$search['number_1']'` got some excess quotes there.

Comment: What is the expected output for example when user enters one of three values or a partial value?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it into one long string?

```
$order_billing = $post['order_billing_1']."-".
                 $post['order_billing_2']."-".
                 $post['order_billing_3'];
```

You can then use this in a simple query.

Please note I used `$post` and not `$_POST` to mimic what you did.

Comment: @SalmanA Because the question ends with 3 strings and wonders how these can be used in a query to match a value in the `order_billing` column. That column contains a string, like `19001-00001-32222`, so now all the values in this column can be compared, using a simple query, with the concatenated string in `$order_billing`.

Answer (score 0):

In plain SQL you want

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE order_billing = CONCAT('13344','-','02351','-','16072')
```

`order_billing` is a single column so needs to be searched with a single string. `CONCAT()` puts your three input fields into a single string.  There are plenty of other ways to do that too.

Beware SQL injection. And think about normalization.

Comment: *"Beware SQL injection."* Codeigniter's `like()` and `or_like()` should protect SQL injections but that SQL injections anti-SQL injection part is really sloppy done in Codeigniter.. I checked the code in the past how it was done i was shocked to find out it was a custom function which protected based on [Special Character Escape Sequences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) and it does the same for other vendors, So there might be holes in the protection when the attackers abuses charset mixing

Answer (score 0):

`like '%something%'` searches 'something' between some other text

let's say you are searching for '1234'

for order billing 1 use -> `like '1234-%'`
for order billing 2 use -> `like '%-1234-%'`
for order billing 3 use -> `like '%-1234'`

Comment: @kiko-software 's solution won't work as expected because if a search is made for order billing 2 and the value which is searched for order billing 2 exists in order billing 1, it will show up too.